# Sort vector by sum of a pair array elements

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, lambda

I'm just playing with C++ sort & lambda and wondering if it would possible to sort elements by sum? 
For example:

```
std::sort(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), [&, sum](int a, int b){
return a + b == sum; });
```

I tried the method above, it gives a runtime error: `"Expression: Invalid operator <".`

**Update1**

The example: 
Sum = 4

1 ,2 ,5, 3, 2

I need to group elements the sum of both would equal Sum e.g 4

So it must be grouped like so:

1,3,2,2,5

Can anybody suggest an alternative solution? I'm just lazy to achieve it using a dumb iteration.

Thanks.

Comment: Sum of what? Sort needs a `<` function between each pair of elements, in your case `a` and `b`. So summing `a` and `b` wouldn't make sense. Can you show an unsorted example list and what you'd like it to sort to?

Comment: I got that already, so because of that I'm asking an alternative solution Without using Iterator!

Comment: @ProblemSolver I'm glad you've got that, because I still don't. Explain clearly how you want to sort. Give me an example of two elements, and which one is greater.

Comment: Offhand, it sounds like you're trying to partition your input into pairs of elements that sum to a particular value, and other elements that don't. Your edit seems to confirm this.

Comment: What are you compiling with? That *should* compile (whether or not it does something reasonable though...)

Comment: Your example is even more confusing now! `sort` isn't meant to "group" anything. And even so, the output in your example doesn't have neighboring pairs that sum to 4. Literally only 1 pair has that property.

Comment: @Cyber: That's the point. The pair that satisfies the property is at the beginning, the rest are after the partition point.

Comment: This is not a job for `std::sort`. It's closer to `std::partition`, but still not really right (`std::partition` works on individual elements, not finding pairs that satisfy a predicate). I'm pretty sure you're stuck writing your own code here.

Comment: But the pre-grouping list doesn't even contain the same elements as the post-grouping list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) requires a predicate that compares elements. That predicate must establish [strict weak ordering](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare), one important property of which is if `pred(a, b)` returns true, `pred(b, a)` must return false. Your lambda does not satisfy this property.

Comment: It's not a compile-time requirement that `sort` be a strict-weak ordering... just a logical one. I can sort a vector with `[](int, int){return false}`. That would be dumb, but I can do it.

Comment: @Barry: Well, you can *compile* with that. What will happen at run time is a different question.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yeah I know. That's why I'm confused as to where `"Expression: Invalid operator <"` came from.

Comment: @Barry It is not clear what your point or argument is.

Comment: Ok, Seems like There is no way to achieve that without using iterator -_- Thanks for the help guys anyway.

Comment: @Barry: I'd guess it was a run-time error, though it's difficult to be sure.